# Is it possible to configure a virtual application to use a separate app pool in azure web apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We've recently migrated our site from Azure Cloud Services to use Web Apps.

Previously we had one main website application, which has a virtual application at /forums - in cloud services we configured this to use a separate app pool to the main website.

Whilst we've had no issues adding a virtual directory and deploying to it, we seem to be unable to configure a separate app pool, is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a description on the Azure site, [Migrate an enterprise web app to Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/#elements-verified-during-compatibility-analysis)

> Application Pools – In Web Apps, each site and its child applications run in the same application pool. If your site has multiple child applications utilizing multiple application pools, consolidate them to a single application pool with common settings or migrate each application to a separate web app.

So it seems that currently, we cannot achieve this.